# Optimising a query for Top 5% of users

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008, optimization

On my website, there exists a group of 'power users' who are fantastic and adding lots of content on to my site.

However, their prolific activities has led to their profile pages slowing down a lot. For 95% of the other users, the SPROC that is returning the data is very quick. It's only for these group of power users, the very same SPROC is slow.

How does one go about optimising the query for this group of users?

You can assume that the right indexes have already been constructed.

**EDIT:** Ok, I think I have been a bit too vague. To rephrase the question, how can I optimise my site to enhance the performance for these 5% of users. Given that this SPROC is the same one that is in use for every user and that it is already well optimised, I am guessing the next steps are to explore caching possibilities on the data and application layers?

**EDIT2:** The only difference between my power users and the rest of the users is the amount of stuff they have added. So I guess the bottleneck is just the sheer number of records that is being fetched. An average user adds about 200 items to my site. These power users add over 10,000 items. On their profile, I am showing all the items they have added (you can scroll through them).

Comment: Nowhere near enough information to give any concrete suggestion other than looking at the Query Execution Plans.

Comment: +1 Martin -- OP gives the impression that the queries are slow, which means looking at execution plans. However, I have the sneaky suspicion that he/she has too much data on the profile page and just needs to implement paging for the result sets.

Answer (score 3):

I think you summed it up here:

> An average user adds about 200 items
>   to my site. These power users add over
>   10,000 items. On their profile, I am
>   showing all the items they have added
>   (you can scroll through them).

Implement paging so that it only fetches 100 at a time or something?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can't optimize a query for a specific result set and leave the query for the rest unchanged. If you know what I mean. I'm guessing there's only one query to change, so you will optimize it for every type of user. Therefore this optimization scenario is no different from any other. Figure out what the problem is; is it too much data being returned? Calculations taking too long because of the amount of data? Where exactly is the cause of the slowdown? Those are questions you need to ask yourself.

However I see you talking about profile pages being slow. When you think the query that returns that information is already optimized (because it works for 95%), you might consider some form of caching of the profile page content. In general, profile pages do not have to supply real-time information.

Caching can be done in a lot of ways, far too many to cover in this answer. But to give you one small example; you could work with a temp table. Your 'profile query' returns information from that temp table, information that is already calculated. Because that query will be simple, it won't take that much time to execute. Meanwhile, you make sure that the temp table periodically gets refreshed.

Just a couple of ideas. I hope they're useful to you.

**Edit:**

> An average user adds about 200 items to my site. These power users add over 10,000 items.
>   On their profile, I am showing all the
>   items they have added (you can scroll
>   through them).

An obvious help for this will be to limit the number of results inside the query, or apply a form of pagination (in the DAL, not UI/BLL!).

Comment: +1 All good suggestions. @Nai what is the bottleneck? Is the problem the amount of data returned for these users or the time taken to execute the query?

Answer (score 1):

You could limit the profile display so that it only shows the most recent 200 items.  If your power users want to see more, they can click a button and get the rest of their items.  At that point, they would expect a slower response.

Answer (score 0):

Partition / separate the data for those users then the tables in question will be used by only them.

In a clustered environment I believe SQL recognises this and spreads the load to compensate, however in a single server environment i'm not entirely sure how it does the optimisation.

So essentially (greatly simplified of course) ...

If you havea table called "Articles", have 2 tables ... "Articles", "Top5PercentArticles".
Because the data is now separated out in to 2 smaller subsets of data the indexes are smaller and the read and write requests on a single table in the database will drop.

it's not ideal from a business layer point of view as you would then need some way to list what data is stored in what tables but that's a completely separate problem altogether.

Failing that your only option past execution plans is to scale up your server platform.